# JDBC and ODBC backend information

Tags: database, jdbc, odbc

If I am given the JDBC and ODBC from a site and they aren't giving me what database in the backend they're using (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLServer). Is there a way to know about this information?

Comment: What do you mean, 'are not giving you'? Are you making the documented calls to return this information?

Answer (score 0):

You could manually compare against the examples in [ODBC connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) or [JDBC connection strings](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/AListofJDBCDriversconnectionstringdrivername.htm)

Or you could try some queries against standard tables in each RDBMS type.  E.g. select 'x' from dual; with a result indicating (but not proving) that its an Oracle DB.